# How to bind the Dictionary to LineSeries in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, dictionary, mvvm, wpftoolkit

I am very new for C# & WPF, I am not able to bind the data to lineSeries.

I am gone through with some of the examples, but I didn't understand how to bind the data

I need to bind the data which is in the Dictionary.
Plotgraph.cs:

```
internal class Plotgraph : ICommand
{
    private ViewModel viewModel;
    public Plotgraph(ViewModel viewModel)
    {
        this.viewModel = viewModel;
    }
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter) => true;
    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        viewModel.Model.GetParameterValues(viewModel.SelectedParameter.Name);
    }
}
```

I have the chart in Window.xaml

```
<ChartingControls:Chart Title="Parameter Values v/s TimeStamp" x:Name="GraphPlot" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">
        <ChartingControls:LineSeries x:Name="ParameterTimeStamp" 
                Title="{Binding Path=SelectedParameter.Description}" DependentValuePath="Value"
                                     IndependentValuePath="Key" ItemsSource="{Binding PlotParameter}">
        </ChartingControls:LineSeries>
        <ChartingControls:Chart.Axes>
            <ChartingControls:LinearAxis
                    Orientation="X"
                    Title="TimeStamp"
                    Interval="50" Minimum="0" Maximum="{Binding Path=Mission.DataLength}"/>
            <ChartingControls:LinearAxis
                    Orientation="Y"
                    Title="Values"
                    Interval="30" Minimum="{Binding Path=SelectedParameter.MinimumValue}" 
                Maximum="{Binding Path=SelectedParameter.MaximumValue}"/>
        </ChartingControls:Chart.Axes>
    </ChartingControls:Chart>
```

the window.cs looks like

```
public partial class GraphPlotUIWindow : Window
{
    public GraphPlotUIWindow(IViewModel viewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = viewModel;
    }
}
```

I have added PlotParameter in both Iviewmodel and in viewmodel, as below:

IViewModel.cs:

```
Dictionary<int, double> PlotParameter { get; set; }
```

ViewModel.cs:

```
public Dictionary<int, double> plotparameter;
public Dictionary<int, double> PlotParameter
    {
        get
        {
            return plotparameter;
        }

        set
        {
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(PlotParameter));
        }
    }
```

But the dataset is available in Model.cs:

```
public Dictionary<int, double> ParameterDataSet;

public Dictionary<int, double> GetParameterValues(string name)
    {
       var parameterValues =  tcpServiceClient.GetParameterValues(name);

        ParameterDataSet = new Dictionary<int, double>();

        foreach (var item1 in parameterValues)
        {
            var key = item1.TimeStamp;
            var value = item1.Value;
            ParameterDataSet.Add(key, value);
        }
        return ParameterDataSet;
    }
```

I have read the example. still I am in dark, I am not getting where I am doing mistake...

Please help me from this,

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Looks like you're not setting your `plotparameter` member variable when the 'PlotParameter' property is set.

Comment: @ibebbs, As u referred I checked and set the variable now its working fine.. Now I am getting lineseries for the selected parameter..Thanks for your valuable suggestion....